# Fluentbootstrap: Error: A Bootstrap component is finishing but is not at the top of the stack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentbootstrap

I'm using [fluentbootstrap](http://fluentbootstrap.com/) library in my MVC 5 project. I have a simple form that works fine on my machine but gives me error on production server:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A Bootstrap component is finishing but is not at the top of the stack, which is usually an indication that a component has been disposed out of order or that more than one component was created in a single using statement.

Source Error: 

Line 13: {
Line 14:     @form.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName);
Line 15: }  <<== error line
Line 16: 
Line 17: @*@using (Html.BeginForm())

Source File: c:\Article27\Views\Engineers\New.cshtml    Line: 15 

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOperationException: A Bootstrap component is finishing but is not at the top of the stack, which is usually an indication that a component has been disposed out of order or that more than one component was created in a single using statement.]
   FluentBootstrap.Component.Finish(TextWriter writer) +327
   FluentBootstrap.Component.End(TextWriter writer) +49
   FluentBootstrap.ComponentWrapper`2.End() +18
   ASP._Page_Views_Engineers_New_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Article27\Views\Engineers\New.cshtml:15
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
...
```

this is the code in the form:

```
@using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form(FormMethod.Post)
    .SetHorizontal().AddAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data").Begin())
{
    @form.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName);
}
```

the original form had more controls but I removed other parts to find problematic part. and I still see the error even with a single control on the form. It seems like a bug in the library.

Comment: When you publish are you publishing all files?

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to find this - still not used to coming on StackOverflow and searching for my libs :). The error you're seeing is usually caused when a control is created but not disposed before it's container is disposed. Since HTML is a tree, this is primarily a sanity check. Your sample code looks fine to me (you don't need the semicolon after `EditorFor`, but that wouldn't cause a crash). Are you still having this problem? Any chance you could post/send the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found tow situations where this error will occur:

1- When you forget to copy `HtmlAgilityPack.dll` to production server (That's me)!!

2- When you use `@form.EditorFor` and you have a `UIHint` attribute on the corresponding model's property and defined an EditorTemplate. AND you have an error in the template file. But instead of seeing the actual error you see this error.